# advdate and datetime2 with day of week

Tags: date, datetime2, advdate

I'd like to increment the date in the format

[Day of week] [Day] [Month] [Year]

by one each step, but I can't get the day of the week to increment. I've been looking at [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/625446/using-advdate-and-datetime2) but I can't get dow to advance properly.

```
\documentclass{article}


\usepackage[british]{babel}
\usepackage[useregional,showdow]{datetime2}


\usepackage{advdate}

\usepackage{etoolbox}

\makeatletter
\appto\FixDate{%
  \edef\@dtm@currentyear{\the\year}%
  \edef\@dtm@currentmonth{\the\month}%
  \edef\@dtm@currentday{\the\day}%
%  \edef\@dtm@currentdow{\the\dow}%??
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\today 

\AdvanceDate[1] 

\today

\AdvanceDate[1] 

\today

\AdvanceDate[1] 

\today

\AdvanceDate[1] 

\today

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an alternative approach using only [`datetime2`](//ctan.org/pkg/datetime2):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[british]{babel}
\usepackage[useregional,showdow]{datetime2}

\NewDocumentCommand{\TODAY}{}{%
  \DTMifsaveddate{now}{}{\DTMsavenow{now}}% If "now" date doesn't exist, set it
  \DTMusedate{now}% Print date
}

% Partly taken from https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/318012/5764
\newcount\daycount
\NewDocumentCommand{\AdvanceTODAY}{ O{1} }{%
  \DTMsaveddateoffsettojulianday{now}{#1}\daycount% Identify Julian days
  \DTMsavejulianday{now}{\number\daycount}% Set new date
}

\begin{document}

\TODAY

\AdvanceTODAY% Defaults to advance 1 day

\TODAY

\AdvanceTODAY[1] 

\TODAY

\AdvanceTODAY[2] 

\TODAY

\end{document}
```

Comment: Excellent thanks so much!